# PDF is not rendered on all the browsers using Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am generating dynamic .pdf file using asp.net, on some browsers e.g firefox displays the pdf as expected but on I.E & Safari its giving a "Save As" rather than displaying it in the browser. I have used an iFrame for the same. Also to display pdf file is it mandate that the client should have adobe reader or some plugin to display the pdf?

```
    protected void bttnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
      string FilePath = Server.MapPath("sample.pdf");
      WebClient User = new WebClient();
      Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(FilePath);
      if (FileBuffer != null)
      {
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
     }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: it depends on adobe plugin, if you not installed that plugin for I.E. or Safari then it will ask to save file rather then to open a pdf file

Comment: Thanks for quick response. Also can you please recommend some standard way to render pdf on all the browsers, considering both the scenarios i.e. client having adobe plugin installed / not installed.

Comment: as per you mentioned that you are using iframe, so if iframe able to find plugin, it will render pdf and show that pdf file else it will not render and pass whole pdf file to browser, so browser will unable to understand what to do with that pdf and as per it's by default action, it will ask to save file

Comment: Please check the updated code without using an iFrame, will this render on all the browsers? Also please suggest a recommended way of rendering pdf on all the browsers.

Comment: Please take note that there is a bug in chrome that it wont display pdfs with forms in them.

Answer (score 0):

in aspx file :

```
<div>
    <iframe id="myFrame" runat="server" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

in cs file :

```
myFrame.src="yourPDFPath"
```

for example

```
myFrame.Src = "http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://path.com/to/your/pdf.pdf&embedded=true";
```

Comment: Pranav all my pdf files are dynamically generated & stored on our server.So do i need to upload my pdf  document on the google server & then map the url to the iFrame? Thanx in advance

Comment: no, you need to pass just path where you stored your pdf file.
for example,
if you stored at myfolder/mypdf.pdf then

myFrame.Src = Server.MapPath("myfolder/mypdf.pdf");

Answer (score 0):

When I have done this I have also added a content disposition. In the code (can't share it all as it is production code) there is a function that finds a record in the database and returns a FileHandle.

The function returns a FileHandle:

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

var fileHandle = new FileHandle
{
    FileStream = stream,
    ContentType = "application/pdf",
    Filename = fileDownloadName
};
```

where filePath is the path to the file (e.g. Server.MapPath("sample.pdf") ). In the controller action I have:

```
var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition
{
    // for example foo.bak
    FileName = fileHandle.Filename,

    // always prompt the user for downloading, set to true if you want 
    // the browser to try to show the file inline
    Inline = true,
};
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
return File(fileHandle.FileStream, fileHandle.ContentType);
```

Comment: Thanks Nigel. Can you please update the above code with the path of the pdf file? e.g http://mydomain/pdf/sample.pdf? Also will the above code render on all the browsers irrespective of the client having adobe reader / some pdf reader installed?

Comment: I have fleshed out the answer a bit more. This has been tested in IE, Chrome and the Fox. PDF files we have are then rendered inline in the browser - either directly going to the link or via an iframe. (Note: fileDownloadName is the name of the file (without path))

Answer (score 0):

Add below line before the line `Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);`.

`Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");`

add this header to reponse , so that PDF files will opened in browser itself.